# How to use mongoose to filtered the deleted users?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Heyyy guys ,

I need a function that ,when you delete a user ,you and that user been deleled won't see each orther in their users list .
I am not sure how can I make this happen .Could you please help me ?

Thank you so much in advance !

**User schema :**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");


const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
   
    userName: {
      type: String,
    },

    deleteList: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
    beenDeletedList: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
  }

);



const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = UserInfo;
```

**Get all filted users
(I am not sure how can filter all the users been deleted and show the rest of the users) :**

```
exports.getSortedUsers = async (req, res, next) => {
   const user = await User.findById(req.body._id);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude an array of object from mongoose find with the [$nor](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/nor/) operator.

In your case, you can try something like this :

```js
exports.getSortedUsers = async (req, res, next) => {
   const users = await User.find({ $nor: beenDeletedList });
}
```

With beenDeletedList is the list of users blocked (deleted) by you.